# How to send data to client with node express when client has not ask for?

Tags: node.js, express

My Question is above. I want that when an event triggered like a new Mail comes in or an other client has connected to the server, my application send to the existing connection a request(?) which say something like "Hey you not alone !". I know how to answer on request from client but how can i send the client information when he has not ask for it explicit.

[i hav draw an simple image to visualize what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnZyx.jpg)

Comment: Search for `websocket`, `long polling` (socket.io is fairly easy to get started, and provides both), `server sent events`

Comment: With websockets i got bad memories. In the last Project with them was my Problem that i always lose the connection to the Server socket when the client switch the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly do this. However, you can archive this by Server-sent Event which is making use of long-polling.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events

Comment: i looking a bit after long-polling and it seems like it is what i need, thangs ^^

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are looking for a way to send data / message from server to client side.

if so there are two ways to do it.

1. Create an API and pool is after certain interval of time from client side.
2. Create a socket server, connect your client with socket which will give you maintain the socketId on server